# How to evaluate a function passed by a string in c#

Tags: c#, methods, eval

I would like to know if there is a way in c# to execute a method, if we have only it's name in a string ?

```
string methodname="method"
this.RunMethod(methodname)
```

Something like that ?

Thanks :)

Comment: and the keyword to search is 'Reflection'

Comment: @AdrianIftode: the type would be `this.GetType()`

Comment: yes you can, but I would caution you not to. Reflection is a very powerful tool, but isn't meant for everyday use. Typically you only need this when building dynamic infrastructure/frameworks. but for everyday business solutions encapsulating change using common design patterns is enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a generic method to invoke methods by their name on any instance you want this way:

```
public void RunMethodOn(object obj, String methodName,params Object[] args)
        {
            if(obj != null)
            {
                System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = null;
                method = obj.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
                if (method != null)
                    method.Invoke(obj, args);
            }
        }
```

And the use it to call a method on your own instance as you ask:

```
public void RunMethod(String methodName,params Object[] args)
            {
                   ExecuteOn(this, methodName, args);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
t.InvokeMember("method", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Only good for static methods. OP is trying to call instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Type type = GetType("MyType");
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
methodInfo.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used seomthing like this:

```
typeof(StringValidator<T>).GetMethod(restriction.Operacion.Nombre).Invoke(null, param) as IList<T>;
```

based on the type of the class that contains the method (StringValidator) then I get the method by it's name restriction.Operacion.Nombre, and Invoke it.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met) has what you are looking for namely:

```
String s = (String)calledType.InvokeMember(
                methodName,
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | 
                    BindingFlags.Static,
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

(Obviously this may change depending on return types etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need the type, the method name, and an instance if the method is not static

Check [Reflection: How to Invoke Method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very nicely with an extension method:

```
public static class MethodEx
{
    public static void RunMethod(
         this object target,
         string methodName,
         params object[] values)
    {
        var type=target.GetType();
        var mi = 
          type.GetMethod(methodName,values.Select(v=>v.GetType()).ToArray());
        mi.Invoke(target,values);
    }
}
```

...and use it as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var m=new Monkey();
    m.RunMethod("A",1);
    m.RunMethod("A","frog");
}

class Monkey
{
    public void A(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int A called");
    }
    public void A(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string A called");
    }
}
```

which will choose the right overload according to the supplied params, so the code above gives output:

> int A called
>
> string A called

I leave better error handling to the OP.