# Convert an array to single elements to pass to a function

Tags: c#, arrays

Difficult to give correct title, sorry for this.

I have a class (I cannot modify) with a function

`f(string arg1, string arg2, ..., string n)`.

I have an array `var arr = new string[n] { ..... }`

How can I convert array items to be passed fo function `f` without the need to write

`f(arr[0], arr[1], ..., arr[n-1])`?

Comment: You should be able to use reflection for this for example

Comment: How is N specified? I mean, it can't be dynamic as you have a function with N parameters?

Comment: @Esailija: well, I could, but writing a function using Reflection is harder than write parameters manually. Naturally if they are a few (I have 20)

Comment: @Marco well you can define your own function that takes `params`, and uses reflection to pass them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may think about using a reflection.

In that case, on *invoke* ou have a possibility to pass an array of arguments:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(instanceOfClass, parametersArray)
```

Can look on example:

[Reflection: How to Invoke Method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters)

Keep atention on fact that in *this* case according to the [MethodBase.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) documentation you have an `object[]` array, so you have to deal with `boxing/unboxing`, don't know if all this effort *really* worths, just simply passing arguments, in ordinary way.

Comment: I didn't think about this, you're correct. I'll take a look at it in a few hours and be back to you. Thanks!

Comment: In my specific case probably it doesn't worth (params are 20), but just to have an idea if I need something that takes longer. My concern is readability of the code: writing down `arr[0],....,arr[19]` is not funny nor maintainable... What do you think?

Comment: @Marco: well, if the only conern is the *readability* and *scallability* it worths to check out this solution. In other cases, just keep ordinar way of doing stuff.

Comment: @Marco Honestly, the size of the code isn't the first thing to think about for the maintainability. The complexity and the ability to generate error on compilation if you change your code is much more important IMO. I would go for the 20 parameters as Michel Keijzers said, as reflection removes strongly typing and adds complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can use reflection but I think that would be even more ugly than the 20 parameters written fully.

If you only need it on one location, I would say just call it with 20 parameters. If you need it on multiple places, make a function with 20 parameters in your own program and call that function within your own program everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

using reflection such as MethodInfo would be one of your choice.

[1] Get the method f's info (pseudo code):

```
 MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof (TheClassWhereFuncfExists).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public...);
```

[2] Using linq to get f's method info

```
MethodInfo fmi= methodInfos.Where(item=> item.Name=="f").FirstOrDefault();
```

[3] once you get the fmi, you can the programmatically call it:

```
fmi.Invoke(...)
```

Pseudo code only, not thoroughly tested.