# How do I pass parameters in a control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controls

I would like to pass a string parameter (name) in the following line. How do I do that?

```
string name = "First Name";
//How do I pass "First Name" in the function?
tempControl.GetType().GetMethod("LoadAnswers").Invoke(tempControl, null);
```

Comment: This may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the `Invoke` method an object array of arguments:

```
tempControl.GetType().GetMethod("LoadAnswers").Invoke(tempControl, new object[] { name });
```

But... I am confused as to why you don't just call the method on the `tempControl` object:

```
tempControl.LoadAnswers(name);
```

??

EDIT

As @Jason P mentioned in the comments, if you cast your control to the right type (for the sake of argument, `MyUserControl`) you'll be able to access the method without using reflection. This would be a much more readable and performant solution:

```
var myControl = (MyUserControl)tempControl;
myControl.LoadAnswers(name);
```

Comment: I'm using a user control so LoadAnswers is on an ascx page  tempControl = LoadControl("~/Controls/Questionnaire/Qst_rev1.ascx");

Comment: @MrM cast `tempControl` to the actual type, and you'll be able to access its public members without reflection.