# Loading Runtime DLL

Tags: c#, dll, createinstance

I'm trying to load a DLL runtime and invoke a method in one of the classes present in DLL.

Here is where I've loaded the DLL and invoking method,

```
Object[] mthdInps = new Object[2]; 
mthdInps[0] = mScope; 
string paramSrvrName = srvrName; 
mthdInps[1] = paramSrvrName; 
Assembly runTimeDLL = Assembly.LoadFrom("ClassLibrary.dll"); 
Type runTimeDLLType = runTimeDLL.GetType("ClassLibrary.Class1"); 
Object compObject = Activator.CreateInstance(runTimeDLLType, mthdInps); 
Type compClass = compObject.GetType(); 
MethodInfo mthdInfo = compClass.GetMethod("Method1"); 
string mthdResult = (string)mthdInfo.Invoke(compObject, null);
```

Here is the Class(present in DLL) and its method I'm trying to invoke,

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()   {}
        public String Method1(Object[] inpObjs)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is this,
**`Constructor on type 'ClassLibrary.Class1' not found.`**

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading DLLs at runtime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you're passing the method parameters to the class constructor.

This:

```
Object compObject = Activator.CreateInstance(runTimeDLLType, mthdInps);
```

Should be just:

```
Object compObject = Activator.CreateInstance(runTimeDLLType);
```

And then, you call the method with the parameters:

```
string mthdResult = (string)mthdInfo.Invoke(compObject, new object[] { objs });
```

Comment: ya I tried.. now, i'm getting "Parameter count mismatch." error.

Comment: @wesfaith try with this: `(string)mthdInfo.Invoke(compObject, new object[] { objs });` I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])` specifies parameters to the constructor. You need to modify your constructor to take `Object[]`, or call it with just the `Type`, `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`, then call your method passing in the object array.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object[] mthdInps = new Object[2]; 
mthdInps[0] = mScope; 
string paramSrvrName = srvrName; 
mthdInps[1] = paramSrvrName; 
Assembly runTimeDLL = Assembly.LoadFrom("ClassLibrary.dll"); 
Type runTimeDLLType = runTimeDLL.GetType("ClassLibrary.Class1"); 
//do not pass parameters if the constructor doesn't have 
Object compObject = Activator.CreateInstance(runTimeDLLType); 
Type compClass = compObject.GetType(); 
MethodInfo mthdInfo = compClass.GetMethod("Method1"); 

// one parameter of type object array
object[] parameters = new object[] { mthdInps };
string mthdResult = (string)mthdInfo.Invoke(compObject, parameters );
```