# How to load assemblies to the current app domain to the c# project dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load third party `assemblies` *dynamically* to the project and use `reflection` to create instance of their types.

I used:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly1.dll")
Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly2.dll")
Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly3.dll")
```

Also, tried:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Assembly1.dll")
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Assembly2.dll")
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Assembly3.dll")
```

However, I keep getting `The method is not implemented` exception while I try to create instance of one of their type as follow:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly1.dll")
Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly2.dll")
Assembly assembly=  Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly3.dll")
Type type=assembly.GetType("Assembly3.Class1")
object instance=Activator.CreateInstance(type); //throws exception at this point
```

However, if I directly `add reference` to *Assembly1, Assembly2 and Assembly3* in the project and do:

```
Assembly3.Class1 testClass=new Assembly3.Class1();
```

*I get no exception*

I just wanted to know what I'm doing wrong? How do I load assemblies to the project *dynamically*. I'm guessing since creation of `Class1` instance depends on another assembly `Assembly1` and `Assembly2`, so it's failing. So, how do I load all the dependent assemblies dynamically to the `appdomain/loadcontext`.

Greatly appreciate your answers.

Comment: Responded in another thread : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362459/4997569

Comment: Not really! that is loading only _one assembly_ and instantiating it's `type`. I tried that already. But didn't work. I've **multiple assemblies** to load to the "current context" and create an instance

Answer (score 1):

For resolve dependencies you need to handle [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class ExampleClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

        ad.AssemblyResolve += MyAssemblyResolveHandler;

        Assembly assembly = ad.Load("Assembly3.dll");

        Type type = assembly.GetType("Assembly3.Class1");

        try
        {
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static Assembly MyAssemblyResolveHandler(object source, ResolveEventArgs e) 
    {
        // Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly1.dll")
        // Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly2.dll")

        return Assembly.Load(e.Name);
    }
}
```

The *MyAssemblyResolveHandler* triggered for each assembly than not loaded, including dependencies.

Comment: This will get an infinite loop cause calling Assembly.Load(e.name) call the ResolveHandler of CurrentDomain

Answer (score 1):

When using "ad.AssemblyResolve += MyAssemblyResolveHandler", I got the infinite loop described by 'cdie'.

So I tried a couple of thing.  The following was via the MSDNs LoadFrom [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public object InitClassFromExternalAssembly(string dllPath, string className)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(className);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        return instance;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Apparently, the Assembly.LoadFrom method requires the full path of the DLL.

Please note the possible problems loading an assembly via LoadFrom in the link.

Also, the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/18362459#18362459) included by 'ArcangelZith' above has some interesting ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If assembly is referenced, you could do like this to load it by name

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(new AssemblyName("Assembly1.Core"))
```