# Load components from DLL(Assembly) without loading the assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

How to load a component from an `Assembly` without loading the complete `Assembly` in the memory?

Say if I have a `UserControl` UC1 in an `Assembly`, I want to load it either in ***`XAML or c# code`*** without loading the whole assembly file? ***Can I do it?***

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reflection.htm

Comment: You can use Reflection to execute .NET code without linking in compile time. (BTW this is exact way the PowerShell works).

Comment: @DhavalPatel please check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

For code inspection only, you need to read this [article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With that approach, inspected library is not loaded. Unfortunatelly, to execute method, you need to load assembly and methods from assembly as other posts are sugesting.

Comment: I've updated the question, can you check now

Answer (score 0):

From other stack overflow post: [Loading DLLs at runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

> Members must be resolvable at compile time to be called directly from
>   C#. Otherwise you must use reflection or dynamic objects.
>
> ```
> namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
>     using System;
>     using System.Reflection;
>
>     class Program
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\DLL.dll");
>
>             foreach(Type type in DLL.GetExportedTypes())
>             {
>                 var c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
>                 type.InvokeMember("Output", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, c, new object[] {@"Hello"});
>             }
>
>             Console.ReadLine();
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: this will load aseambly... question was if it can be done WITHOUT loading

Comment: True, missed 'without' part while reading..

Comment: @DovydasSopa I've updated the question, can you check?