# Unity: Change code dynamically in 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine, unityscript

I would like to use **Unity to create a 2D game**. I have already read through some tutorials but I couldn't really find an answer to my problem.

As my game should be changeable by an admin (a person should be able to change textboxes and some content of the game before distributing it), **I would like to adapt some code of the game outside the unity program to adapt the whole game**.
Is it possible to do this? If yes, what is the starting point for doing this?

I basically know what to do in Unity but I haven't understand the full structure there yet.

**EDIT**

Example: I create a game in which a user have to collect items falling down the sky. Those items are words by default.
But those items should be adaptable, so that I can change the words' content e.g. outside the engine.

Comment: Regarding your edit:  why not just put the words into some editable file?

Comment: it's not inherent to unity but to general programming, if you want to able to modify a program after it was compiled, you have to create a custom configuration file (xml, json, ...) which contain any adaptable elements and you have to parse it for retrieving values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im no Unity Developer neither an Game Developer.
There are several approaches. First of all, use resources. You shouldn't encode the content of Textboxes in your Code. It could be saved in a Textfile or an XML File. Ingame you load the file and use a collection for the falling words.
Other approach: Build an interface like "fallingWordGenerator", implement it as DLL, and load the DLL on startup ([Loading DLLs at runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)).

Greetings

Comment: As Yonah says.  it's very easy to download a text file from the net inside Unity, just use the `WWW` class.

Comment: Thank you, the WWW class is exactly what I'm looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Within Unity, You Can make use of thé AssetsBundle. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

You can package new codes files, scenes and other content that can be downloaded and integrated at runtime. It does need Unity knowledge, however.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is an application for programmers , designers and even artists . you can create Editors inside you unity project so your game designer can change and adapt data of your games.
Search for **Custom Editors** inside unity.

You can save designer's data into a **ScriptableObject** and use it later in runtime.