# SqlGeometry in C++ Application?

Tags: c++, spatial, sqlgeometry

I've used Microsoft's `SqlGeometry` from [*Microsoft.SqlServer.Types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.aspx) in a C# application and was quite happy with the performance. I saw that it's actual functionality is contained in a native library, *SqlServerSpatial110.dll* (or another number, depending on the SqlServer version it belongs to), since this DLL exposes the common geometry functions like `Overlaps`, `Centroid`, `Buffer` etc.

Is there any chance that I could use that DLL from a **C++** application *directly*, i.e. without going through a managed wrapper (e.g. C++/CLI)? Is there a header file and a lib somewhere that I could use, and maybe some documentation?

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362459/3270427

Comment: By the way, this is common visual c++ question, not sql-spatial-geometry whatever...

Answer (score 1):

You could always use **LoadLibrary** and **GetProcAddress** to load the DLL dynamically [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944(VS.85).aspx)

You can always look up the functions exported by a .dll via tools like `PEtools`/`LordPE` or some advanced disassemblers like `hiew`. The `X-Rays` plugin for `IDA Pro` won't be necessary here but really helps to find out structures and write own .h headers if you really need them.