# How to prevent application from crashing when .dll is missing?

Tags: c#, dll, exception

I want my program in case of missing `.dll` file to notify user about this fact instead of just crashing with `FileNotFoundException` reffering to this `.dll`.

This library is included to the project via refference.

Exception is thrown even before any of my code is executed so I can't hadle 
it.

Comment: It's not possible, you should add dll before compiling the program.

Comment: It's already compiled. I just want to handle the case when program is started but required dll is missing.

Comment: If the project dll is a direct reference, then how does it compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only 2 options are (as far as i know)

- You need to load the dll dynamically and reflect what you need
- Write a loader app to check for the dll before starting your app

This question may get you started on option one

[Loading DLLs at runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

> However : i guess its just easier to make sure they have the dll or
>   include it in the build

Answer (score 0):

During application start up, you can register app domain for any unhandled exception as :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

Your handler should take care of showing appropriate message to user.