# How Can i call other functions in a class from special function(Just with their string names) in C#?

Tags: c#, function, reflection, methods, call

I have a Class by name of `GoldClass`. It has four methods by names `F()`,`S()`,`TH()`,`Fo()`. In the methods `FO()`. I want to call three other methods (F,S,TH) but just use their names like this.

```
public void Fo()
{
    list <string> FuncsList=new list<string>();
    FuncsList.Add("F");
    FuncsList.Add("S");
    FuncsList.Add("TH");

    //NOW I WANT TO CALL THEM BUT USE MY STRINGS IN MY FUNCSLIST  
}
```

I used Reflection at first ... but I am assigning some values to public variables in my class..and when reflection make new instance all my data in public variables is lost.

Comment: ...you can pass instances when calling via reflection..

Comment: Well may be you should ask about why things got lost then, as reflection of some description is basically the way to go.

Comment: You can find the answer in detail from the following Post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters

Answer (score 3):

Is there any particular reason, you need to store them as strings. If they're all parameterless void methods in the same class, you could store them as `Action`s

```
void Main()
{
    A();
}

public void A()
{
    List<Action> list = new List<Action>();
    list.Add(B);
    list.Add(C);
    list.Add(D);

    foreach(Action action in list){
        action();
    }
}


public void B()
{
    Console.WriteLine("B Called");
}


public void C()
{
    Console.WriteLine("C Called");
}


public void D()
{
    Console.WriteLine("D Called");
}
```

Having said that, It's not at all clear why you need to do this at all. Why do you need to do this dynamically. would the following not suffice.

```
public void FO()
{
    F();
    S();
    TH();
}
```

Comment: Good...But i'm sending list for the Fo from other class
actually it is Fo(List<string> Bla)

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a function with a string.
Check this link for more information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary of strings and actions for this:

```
public class Example
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> _map = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

    public Example()
    {
        _map["A"] = A;
        _map["B"] = B;
        _map["C"] = C;
    }

    public void A() { }
    public void B() { }
    public void C() { }

    public void CallByString(string func)
    {
        if(_map.ContainsKey(func))
            _map[func]();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Example example = new Example();
example.CallByString("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
Either use reflection.
Or use some kind of switch statement, the later is faster.

```
public void Fo()
{
    list <string> FuncsList=new list<string>();
    FuncsList.Add("F");
    FuncsList.Add("S");
    FuncsList.Add("TH");

    foreach(String name in FuncsList)
        CallNamedMethod(name);
}

private void CallNamedMethod(string name)
{
    switch(name)
    {
        case "F":
            F();
            return;

        case "S":
            S();
            return;

        case "TH":
            TH();
            return;

        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

If you have a huge amount of different methods that you can call, you may create a dictionary with names and delegates.

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: It's a List<string> not just string

Comment: I have corrected the source so you can see how it is supposed to be used, too.

Answer (score -1):

Call Direct assembly where they belongs c# cannot know is their references