# How to add buttons that would run methods from dlls which are not yet added- dynamic programing?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, reflection

I have created a application with some bar on top of it, lets say that bar control is name `BarControl`. That application is installed at a few customers. Then one of them need some additional features that the app must have. I do not want to change only that one and then maintain 2 line of same application so what I need to do is to change application so that:

1. I create datatable on the server, in that table will be the name of  the buttons, the buttons caption and name of method that will be run when that button is clicked( ok that i know how to do :) )
2. When the app starts, it checks that table and for each record it creates a button, adds it to my `BarControl` and make it so if button is pressed then method (which name is in the same record) is launched. The program Looks for that method in a DLL which is placed in a plugin folder. Lets say that method take one argument which is a `string`.

Could you please help me with that topic, maybe some code, maybe a bit of advice what do I need to do to make this work.

Comment: A search for "C# plugin framework" should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Windows forms or WPF? In case of WPF prism can come to the rescue with its modules. You can have custom modules and module discovery where even complete GUI regions can be customised in a separate assembly.

Comment: possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540066/calling-a-function-from-a-string-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894926/how-can-i-call-other-functions-in-a-class-from-special-functionjust-with-their