# how to resolve circular dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, circular-dependency

I have added another project "xml" to my project "synchronise".

So program.cs (in the xml project) runs the getDetails(), which runs the FectchDetails() in the synchronise project and returns the result as an object to the xml/getDetails().

If an error occurs in the Synchronise/FecthDetails() I want to re run the xml/getDetails().

Ive tried xml.getDetails, but it is saying it doesnt exist, because its not reference to the project so I try to add the xml project to the synchroinse but its telling me I cant do this as it would cause circular dependency....how can I resolve this

thanks

Comment: You really need to show some code, to make your question clearer.

Comment: Try using reflection. This post will probably help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters

Comment: forget reflection... too much overhead for what? I don't see a solution using reflection.

Anyway. getDetails {
try{
FetchDetails();
} catch (Exception e) {
FetchDetails()
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encounter an error within  Synchronise/FecthDetails(), propbably you can throw an application exception and catch that in xml/getDetails. Then you can decide whether to re-try or inform the user about it.

I am sorry if I misunderstood you question. if possible post some psuedo-code.

Comment: No that was perfect, threw a catch which was caught in xml/details, then simply logged the error and re ran the function, which works. thanks

Comment: Really? You "threw a catch". 
If writing code or anything else.... Someone may read it and try to understand it.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you have a project X depending on project Y  (**X --> Y**) , and project Y depending on project X ( **Y --> X**).

In other words, something like: **( X <---> Y)**

This situation means that the compiler does not know what to compile first, and therefore complains.

To solve this, look for common things / pieces of logic that can be moved out from one or both of the projects, and **create a third project that can be built before both of the others.**

Place all common stuff in this new project, and you should be fine; your dependency should then be as below, where it does not matter if X or Y is compiled first, as long as Z is compiled before both of them:

**( X --> Z <-- Y )**

Answer (score 1):

You get circular dependency when:

A depends on B and B depends on A.

If you think both need this dependency then they should belong to one project.

Comment: Well, either that, or you could move the common logic that they both need out into a third project, which both can depend on individually.

Comment: or a Callback... sry. .net may call it event - register a function to be called in an error-case

Answer (score -1):

you can move **FetchDetails()** to another project and reference to this project from both **xml** and  **synchronise** projects