# Circular dependency with special exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

So basically I had the problem with circular dependency ---> [how to resolve circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853067/how-to-resolve-circular-dependency)

Application A-> Application B.   If problem in B, threw an exception which is caught in A, and if the ex.message="error in B", then re-run the function in program A again.

Problem being now I want to throw a special exception. So when it returns to A

```
try
{
x = (List<POSUnitRecord>)GalwayPortal.Download_POS(url, null, new XmlResultInterpreter());
}
catch (XMLFailureException)
{
x = (List<POSUnitRecord>)GalwayPortal.Download_POS(url, null, new XmlResultInterpreter());
}
```

But the 'XMLFailureExeption.cs' is in application A. SO I tried adding this class to B. then throwing the `throw new XMLFailureException();` error but it just returns to a normal exception in A, where it should be catching this and rerunning the function? Please advise?

Comment: Putting a re-try in the catch statement is very dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move XMLFailureException into a class library that is referenced by both A and B.