# Calling numbered method or method named by a string

Tags: c#, string, function, methods, numbered

I have 100 method like

```
    public void function1() {}
    public void function2() {}
    ....
    public void function100() {}
```

The question is how can i call these function without calling them one by one?
or how can i call a function from a string like:

```
    string S = "TheFunction"+x.Tostring()+"()";
```

Comment: Can you just pass the number into the function as a parameter?

Comment: Duplicate shows how to call function with parameters (which covers your case), there probably more specific duplicate - feel free to search for "C# invoke method by name".

Answer (score 0):

What class are your methods on?  You can get an array of the methods in your class like so:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(YourClassNameHere).GetMethods();
```

Then you can loop and invoke:

```
String baseName = "function";
foreach(var item in methods) {
   //Check name
    if (item.Name.SubString(0, baseName.Length) == baseName) {
       item.Invoke(classInstanceOfYourClass,null);
    }
}
```

`classInstanceOfYourClass` is an object instance of the class on which you are doing this.  The second parameter of invoke, (I set it to `null`) is for passing arguments to the method.  If you pass `null`, you are saying that the method has no arguments.

Comment: Added further detail.

Comment: @Tranoze, did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is Reflection. You can take a look at the code in this answer [Reflection: How to Invoke Method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters).