# In Java, invoke method using reflection and without giving invoker object type and multiple parameters type?

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

My question is, how to invoke a method using reflection, with giving invoker object and **multiple** parameters, **without giving invoker object type and parameters type and without calling API.**

That is

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setNameAndClass("John", "1D"); // Method 0
```

can be replaced by

```
MyMethodUtils.invoke(student, "setNameAndClass", Object[] {"John", "1D"}); // Method 1
```

where the `invoke()` method is made by JDK methods.
It can be in other signature if it fulfill the requirement.

### My research and study

I cannot find any related solution in StackOverflow.
[This answer need class list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)
[This looks pretty close but it is C# and calling API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters)

I am able to make the `invoke()` method like this.

```
MyMethodUtils.invoke(student, "getNameAndClass"); // Method 2 (no parameters)
MyMethodUtils.invoke(student, "setNameAndClass", Object[] {"John", "1D"},
Class[] {String.class, String.class}); // Method 3 (with multiple parameters but inconvenient to use)
```

Method 2, 3 works properly. However, when I tried to implement the Method 1 (what I want), it is working only when the type is exact match.

For example, if the method is like

```
setMarks(String name, Collection<Integer> marks);
```

native invoking works but reflection don't

```
student.setMarks("John", new ArrayList<Integer>()); //works
MyMethodUtils.invoke(student, "setMarks", "John", new ArrayList<Integer>()); // getMethod() method always cannot find a proper method
```

Is it impossible? Or is there ways to implement so?

Comment: What you want to do is possible.  Can you post your code?

Comment: Finally I've made a method which fulfilled the above requirement (support muiltiple parameter). But I am not sure why I cannot answer in this question

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis May the duplicate question you've given have gave some hints for me, there is no existing information for having multiple parameters passing. I may post my answer which that answer cannot provide. Is it still a duplicate? Thanks

Comment: You can post your answer there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As you wish, if you think it is better