# How to get the static type of a property?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to reference the type of a property on a class and I can't figure out the syntax:

```
List<IChildInfo<typeof(MappingModel.identifier)>> mappings;
```

Is this possible in .NET?

```
public class MappingModel
{
    public long identifier { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: just do: `List<IChildInfo<typeof((new MappingModel).identifier)>> mappings;`

Comment: @DamienFlury That doesn´t even compile.

Comment: Did you google that? There are dozens of questions like yours. Some come also with the link to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ooops, wanted to say `List<IChildInfo<typeof((new MappingModel()).identifier)>> mappings;` of course... (Or a different constructor). Missed the brackets there

Comment: @DamienFlury Yeah, that still won't work... You can't use `typeof` or `new` in a type declaration, you only use types.

Comment: @DavidG Oh yeah, you're totally right! While `typeof()` would've been wrong anyway, `.GetType()` apparently doesn't work either with generics, because their type needs to be compile-time-constant

Answer (score 2):

The code you've presented won't work because the compiler has to create a specialized type for that particular list using the type you've specified.

The easiest way of fixing that would be to make a generic specialization "on the fly" ( or at run-time ).

*example code:*

```
// retrieve the property which type you want to get
var propertyInfo = typeof(MappingModel).GetProperty("identifier");
// get that property's type
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

// now that you have a property type you can make a specialized generic type:
Type ichildtype = typeof(IChildInfo).MakeGenericType(propertyType);
// create a type definition for that particular list
Type listtype = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(ichildtype);
// create an instance of that list
Activator.CreateInstance(listtype);
```

[Try this online](http://rextester.com/HBU36368)

Comment: Appreciate the work but I was just looking for syntax sugar :)

Comment: @CoreyAlix Yes, I thought about that but wanted to give some alternative way of achieving something similar. Which you can use to make it work a bit the way you wanted. Hope that it helped in any way :)

Answer (score 1):

First examine the type of your surrounding class, then get its properties:

```
var p = typeof(MappingModel).GetProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "identifier");
```

Or also:

```
var p = typeof(MappingModel).GetProperty("identifier");
```

Now you can get the type of the property via `PropertyType`:

```
var t = p.PropertyType;
```

However as this is a *runtime*-information teher´s no way for the *compiler* to create an instance of a list of that type. You can create an interface that your type implements and then create a list of it:

```
var l = new List<IChildInfo<MyInterface>>();
```

where the type of `MappingModel.identifier` implements `MyInterface`. But this assumes `IChildInfo` to be co-variant:

```
interface IChildInfo<out T> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Reflection to that.

I'm not sure of what exactly you want to do but you can get all the property of a class doing :

```
typeof(MappingModel).GetProperties();
```

Then you can play with the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of the property, but you won't be able to use it as a generic argument using normal syntax. You can use `MethodInfo` to invoke a method that would use `mappings`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters) may prove to be helpful to you.