# How to take either of the type as a parameter for a method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have two classes with same name and same structure but coming from different namespace. For example,

```
class A
{
  int a;
  double b;
  void func()
  {
    //something
  }
}
```

Now I have a method which interacts with object from one namespace

```
void operation(xyz.A a)
{
  // perform some operation
}
```

I want to reuse the same code for other object also(coming from different namespace)

How can I do that?

I have tried using Generics for this purpose but failed.
Here is what I tried,

```
void operation<T>(T a)
{
  a.func();//error
  // perform some operation
}
```

I got error saying T does not contain a definition for 'func' and no accessible extension method 'func' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Do these classes both implement a common interface? If not, do you control these classes, and can make them implement a common interface?

Comment: As already stated by @ZoharPeled, you cannot do this unless you can make both classes implement the same interface. Alternatively you can make your `operation` method accept a `dynamic` input object, but then you are throwing away all type safety which defeats the purpose of using C#.

Comment: Unfortunately, these classes do not implement common interface neither I cannot make them implement. @ZoharPeled

Comment: Use `dynamic` as parameter type. Or you can use `object` type and downcasting inside method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to have an common Interface, as mentioned in the comments. There are ways over Reflection to call members using their name. But I would not recommend this. This is not really save when something changes and - I am not sure about that - not necessarely performant. But anyway, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters), even with using of parameters. It gives you an impression of what it has to look like.

**Answer 1**

Anyway, here is the Interface Example:

```
using BaseNamespaceAbcAndXyzSee;

namespace abc
{
    class A : IA

    {
        public void Foo() { }
    }
}

namespace xyz
{
    class A : IA
    {
        public void Foo() { }
    }
}

namespace BaseNamespaceAbcAndXyzSee
{
    interface IA
    {
        void Foo();
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like that:

```
  static void ExecuteFoo(IA aClass)
  {
      aClass.Foo();
  }
```

**Answer 2 (dynamic)**

You could also make the function acepting the "type" dynamic. This alows you more easily to execute a function, without knowing the type. But as the reflection method, it's not save to changes. When you write sonething wrong, it will throw an exception:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new abc.A();
        ExecuteFoo(a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ExecuteFoo(dynamic aClass)
    {
        aClass.Foo();
        aClass.Bar(); //-> Exception
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Malior, but I cannot make these classes implement any interface.

Comment: @HarshRaj, in this case you can only make the reflection variation, or using the dynamic keyword. I updated the answer to this.

Comment: thank you @malior , use of dynamic keyword helps me out of this problem