# How to create the class instances dynamically and call the implementation

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I have various interfaces and I need to be able to call them. Here is the base class:

```
public class MyActorBase<TChild>: ActorBase where TChild : MyActorBase<TChild>
{
    public MyActorBase()
    {
       var actors =  ChildClass
           .GetInterfaces()
           .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IActorMessageHandler<>))
           .Select(x=> (arguments: x.GetGenericArguments(), definition: x))
           .ToImmutableList();

       if (actors.Any())
       {
           var ty = actors.First();
           var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(ty.definition, true);

           // how to call method implementation
       }

    }

    protected sealed override bool Receive(object message) => false;
    private Type ChildClass => ((this as TChild)?? new object()).GetType();
}


public interface IActorMessageHandler<in T>
{
    Task Handle(T msg);
}
```

I read these blog post:

1. [Dont use Activator.CreateInstance](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/)
2. [Linq Expressions](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/)
3. [Creating objects performance implications](https://ayende.com/blog/3167/creating-objects-perf-implications)

The writers already knew the type at compile time hence were able to cast correctly. I do not know anything at compile time so I cannot use a generic method or typecast it using () operator or as operator.

> **UPDATE**: I think people are not getting the idea of what I want to achieve. so consider this. I made a nuget package which anyone can
>   depend upon. Somewhere in the world, someone writes this code:

```
    public class MyMessage
    {
        public int Number { get; }

        public MyMessage(int number) => Number = number;
    }

    public class MyNewActor: MyActorBase<MyNewActor>, IActorMessageHandler<MyMessage>
    {
        public Task Handle(MyMessage msg)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

I want that any class that implements the **IActorMessageHandler**, i should be able to call its method **Handle(T msg)**. so while I was able to instantiate it (considering that I'm not using any dependency injection) how can I call the method in the most efficient way?

**Is there any alternate to reflection?**

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to use the same reflection code you have used to discover and create an instance.

Comment: i have read a few blog posts about it. Problem is all the blogs know the class at compile time so they typecast it correctly. My case if different. I don't know the class at compile time so I cannot typecast it by using typecasting or even as operator.

Comment: So you haven't found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters or https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/10/10/dynamically-invoking-a-method-with-reflection-in-net-c/ ?

Comment: "how can I call the method in the most efficient way?" - if you're doing all that reflection and LINQ *in the constructor*, frankly "efficient" already flew out the window... you might want to move `actors` to be a `static readonly` field so it only gets built once? (presumably using `typeof(TChild)` or something instead of the `this as TChild` stuff?)

Comment: Another option would be to make your message handler interface non-generic. Then it can be called directly.

Comment: users of my interface should be able to define their own message classes and have different implementations using the generic interface. I cannot use non generic one and want to let programmers typecast it to anything they like

Comment: Non generic version is trivial : `interface IActorMessageHandler { Type SupportedType {get;} Task Handle(object obj); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use `Activator.CreateInstance` it's very much expensive. instead, you may use `Expression.Lamda` to create objects in an efficient way.

```
  var object =  Expression.Lambda<Func<IActorMessageHandler<TChild>>>(Expression.New(ty.definition.Value.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) ?? throw new 
    Exception("Failed to create object"))
                        ).Compile()();
```

Comment: [This post](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/february/making-reflection-in-net-work-faster/) seems to conclude that expression construction is slower than activator construction. I'm not an expert though, what do you think?

Comment: @CorentinPane I edited my post and now it contains an example of how the users should be using it,

Comment: I have done a benchmark  and I can see compiled expression is the fastest one

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `dynamic` keyword? This is basically optimized reflection nicely wrapped for you:

```cs
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(ty.definition, true);
Task t = obj.Handle(msg); //need to define msg before
```

It bypasses compile-time checks and defers method look-up at run-time.

Note that it will fail at run-time if no resolution for the `Handle` method can be performed.

[This blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/06/26/c-4.0-dynamics-vs.-reflection.aspx) concludes that `dynamic` ends up being much quicker than reflection when called fairly often because of caching optimizations.

Comment: is it faster than the tedious MethodInfo and Invoke()?

Comment: yes, there are optimizations for `dynamic` compared to reflection. I'll try to find sources.